# How can i use SQL Server connections with integrated security and an SQL login from same MVC EF app?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller, database-connection

I've built an intranet hosted MVC/EF/C# application that uses windows authentication and identity impersonation and connects to SQL server using integrated security. The EF connection string looks like:

```
<add name="BgEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Bg.csdl|res://*/Models.Bg.ssdl|res://*/Models.Bg.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxxxxxxx;initial catalog=Bg_Dev;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is great for regular app users.
I now need to open a controller up to all users on the intranet, but I can't add everyone in the company as users to the database. I'd like to use a generic SQL Server login to access the database from this controller.
Can I switch connection strings in this controller?

Comment: Did you check this article before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979124/mvc5-simple-membership-default-membership/23979181#23979181

Answer (score 0):

So what worked for me was setting the connection string on the database context per Rodion's post here [Configure multiple database Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308378/configure-multiple-database-entity-framework-6).

I'm sure there's better ways, and i assume that this first connects to the db using the connection string specified in web.config first, then reconnects using the second connection string. But it gets the result.

```
    private bg db = new bg();
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "data source=xxx;initial catalog=bg;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Id=xxx;Password=yyy;App=EntityFramework";
```

;